# apply gradient on background-color

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-color

My `background image` is supposed to cover the whole background of my website.

Here the body-selector in the css file:

```
body {
    background-image: url(https://img.4plebs.org/boards/tv/image/1432/79/1432798812366.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: black;
}
```

In some weird screen-sizes the picture doesn't cover the screen properly and due to the no-repeat option the "underflow" appears white.

I therefore added the `background-color: black` in my body selector which works as a perfect "fall-back option". The background not covered by the image appears black now.

> **Now I'd like to make the transition between background-color and background-image smother by replacing the simple "black" with a gradient. But I didn't find a solution.**

How I'd like it to be (not working):

```
body { 
    ...
    */apparently not a valid option for background-colour:*/
    background-color: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(1, 3, 0), rgb(26, 31, 38));
}
```

Comment: You might want to use `.html {  }` to target the whole page, and not just the body. The body might not cover the whole viewport.

Comment: I tried that as well, unfortunately it somehow messes with the `cover` functionality of the picture...

Comment: Did you fix the  issue? You have marked Adams answer as the correct one.

Comment: yes the issue is fixed. just wanted to give some feedback. thx for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your `html` code and add the `background` to a container instead of the body then use pseudo classes `div::after` you can do that.

Check this code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
}

.main--container {
  background-image: url(https://img.4plebs.org/boards/tv/image/1432/79/1432798812366.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: black;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.main--container::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main--container">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple backgrounds should do the trick. Something in the lines of:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://img.4plebs.org/boards/tv/image/1432/79/1432798812366.jpg), linear-gradient(to right, rgb(1, 3, 0), rgb(26, 31, 38));
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: a simple "Black" is not what I wanted to achieve. but thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, "Simple black"?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add this to your body:

```
 min-width: 100% !important;
 min-height: vh !important;
```

You need to add `!important` if you're using bootstrap.

Comment: using `!important` is not preferred or good practice anyway! and he doesn't need to use it in this case